# Disable keydown shortcuts if input(s) is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keycode

I have few inputs which you focus them using keycodes.

I am trying to: when focus on inputs, disable the keycodes function and when not focused, enable.

I tried this:

```
var hotkeys_function = false;
if (!hotkeys_function ){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 71) { 
        $("#input1").fadeIn();
        $("#input1").focus().select();
            var hotkeys_function = true;
        }
    });

}
```

And this:

```
if ($("#input1").select()) {
    var hotkeys_function = true;
}
```

but none seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not `$("#input1").select()` but `$("#input1").focus()`.

In fact, no variables are needed, you can just check and return dynamically whether an input is focused or not.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if($("#input1").is(":focus")) return; //Will fail if already focused. 

    if (event.keyCode == 71) { //g 
        $("#input1").fadeIn();
        $("#input1").focus().select();
    }
});
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/Fd2zZ/1/)**.

Comment: There's something else prevent this in the rest of the code. Thanks alot though. I will be checking it.

Comment: @pimvdb true, but he asked (also in his example), about `#input1`, anyway it is very trivial to change the match set to work with any input.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this, without any other variables: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/YnVPQ/.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 71) {
        if($("input").is(":focus")) return; // abort if any focused textboxes

        $("#input1").fadeIn();
        $("#input1").focus().select();
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. What ever I put in the $("input") field doesn't work. It has to be something, that's not in the entire html. It seems that on run, one input is being focused. I tried $("#input1") aswell but again it doesn't focus.

Comment: I'm sorry, it obviously prevented any text from being entered. Please see my edit.